# How to make dynamic div not coverd?

Tags: css

I have a dynamic div that shows idols birthday,
and another div that shows news,
both of them float: right,
is there any css can make them not covered each other?

Comment: just add `overflow:hidden;` to its parents, and also post the question properly.

Comment: you can also apply `clear:both;` to avoid it.